# Django rest framework nested serialization not working properly

Tags: python, django, debugging, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have these serializers in my app:

```
class ScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = ('id',)

class DisciplineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Discipline
        fields = ('id',)


class WriteTeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    disciplines = DisciplineSerializer(many=True)
    schedules = ScheduleSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('phone_number', 'bio', 'price', 'disciplines', 'schedules')
        depth = 1

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        print "\n"
        #Debugging here
        print validated_data
        print "\n"
        print instance.__dict__
        print "\n"

        instance.phone_number = validated_data['phone_number']
        instance.bio = validated_data['bio']
        instance.price = validated_data['price']
        disciplines = validated_data.pop('disciplines')
        schedules = validated_data.pop('schedules')
        for discipline in disciplines:
            try:
                stored_discipline = Discipline.objects.get(id=discipline['id'])
                instance.disciplines.add(stored_discipline)
            except Discipline.DoesNotExist:
                raise Http404

        for schedule in schedules:
            try:
                stored_schedule = Schedule.objects.get(id=schedule['id'])
                instance.schedules.add(stored_discipline)
            except Discipline.DoesNotExist:
                raise Http404
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

As you can see I am trying a nested serialization with the fields `schedules` and `disciplines`. I think I followed the documentation, but the nested serialization is not working when I test it. I printed the `instance` and `validated_data` objects and tested it on the shell.

I start the data in this format:

```
data = {u'phone_number': u'+99999999999', u'bio': u'BIO', u'price': 40, u'disciplines': [{'id': 1}], u'schedules': [{'id': 2}]}
```

I got a teacher instance and started the serializer like this:

```
serializer = WriteTeacherSerializer(teacher, data=data)
```

It shows True on a `serializer.is_valid()` call.

However when I try to save it the `validated_data` and the `instance.__dict__` are like that:

```
#validated_data
{u'phone_number': u'+5584998727770', u'bio': u'BIO', u'price': 40, u'disciplines': [OrderedDict()], u'schedules': [OrderedDict()]}


#instance.__dict__
{'phone_number': u'', 'bio': u'', 'price': 50, 'profile_id': 2, '_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0xb64a6bec>, 'id': 6}
```

They don't seem to notice the nested fields wich makes the `update()` method not work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my Teacher Model as well:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):

    price = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Wrong phone number format.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15, blank=True)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    schedules = models.ManyToManyField(Schedule, related_name='schedules')
    disciplines = models.ManyToManyField(Discipline, related_name='disciplines')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just sending `IDs` then you don't need to add the nested serializer, just specify the field name of the `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField`.

```
class WriteTeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('phone_number', 'bio', 'price', 'disciplines', 'schedules')
```

I am also wondering if it is because you have a `depth=1` flag?

DRF doesn't support nested updates out of the box. You have to override the Serializer's update method, and write your own update logic, so you'd be seeing an error for this warning if you were sending nested data.

Comment: For some reason I had to specify these fields to make the serializer work. The problem was that I was that my view was in someway turning disciplines and schedules objects into string. I just converted them back as object again before start the serializer and it's working now.

Comment: Joab could you please explain a little more or post a code snippet? I am having the same issue

Comment: @JesusAlmaral the issue is that if you want a related object serialized as an object and not a primitive value then you need to use a nested serializer to serialize it: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects